# Allocating (statically) memory at kernel boot time

Tags: c, memory, linux-kernel

I am working with the Linux kernel and would like allocate an array of sub page size statically at boot time (in kernel space), which will later be used by the kernel for scheduling purposes. Could anyone please point me in the best manner to do this?

This memory is never to be explicitly freed during the normal execution of the operating system except implicitly at the end (shutdown).

I am already aware of `alloc_bootmem()`  but I would like to know of/explore other possibilities as well. It would be really great if someone could point me to a snippet of code which uses memory in a similar manner that already exists in the Linux kernel.

Comment: What about Kmalloc()

Comment: That looks like a good option as well. Where in the kernel source would one typically place a kmalloc() call to allocate at boot time?

Comment: What specifically are you talking about  Boot time or run time?

Comment: I'd like to allocate at boot time because it may be used at any time during OS execution by the scheduler.

Comment: FIXMAP perhaps a keyword in your case.

Comment: Look into CMA (contiguous memory allocation).

Answer (score 0):

Some kernel modules are using this technique to allocate DMA Buffer when a large size is needed, for exemple [jazzdma](ftp://ftp.acer.hu/gpl/AS1800/linux-2.4.27/arch/mips/jazz/jazzdma.c) module and [nlm-dma](https://github.com/dh-electronics/linux-imx6qdl/blob/a81067a2ce978f88e63b69d18b0d14a5b962be34/arch/mips/netlogic/common/nlm-dma.c) module

Note that if you are using boot time memory allocator for dma purpose you must use

```
void *alloc_bootmem_low_pages(unsigned long size);
```

instead of

`void *alloc_bootmem_pages(unsigned long size);`

because DMA can acces only low memory type