# share memory allocated at boot time to user space

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, shared-memory, mmap

I am searching a solution to allocate memory from kernel to be accessible by the DMA and shared with user space for fast communication, According to [chap08](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiWz9ni5KnNAhXE0hoKHS9QCf8QFggeMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.oreilly.com%2Fopenbook%2Flinuxdrive3%2Fbook%2Fch08.pdf&usg=AFQjCNGKLzUZByH93jx0KkSl5ePuaXssQA&sig2=1AIstuu9NCcVsCOyFbwmyA) of linux driver3 the only way to allocate huge memory is at boot time method using the function bellow:

```
#include <linux/bootmem.h>
void *alloc_bootmem_low_pages(unsigned long size);
```

i don't know if this memory can be mapped to user space using mmap() like the memory allocated with kmalloc() ?

i have seen those posts but still get no answer

[Allocating a physical memory buffer in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25896231/allocating-a-physical-memory-buffer-in-linux)

[Allocating (statically) memory at kernel boot time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37549510/allocating-statically-memory-at-kernel-boot-time)

Comment: You mean accessible by ISA DMA?

Comment: In my case i am using DMA to transfer data from EIM bus not ISA.